# PHP within HTML doesn't do anything

Tags: php, html

**SOLVED** I saved it as an HTML-document... As PHP-file it works great!

I have create an HTML-page, with some PHP-code in it. For some reason the PHP-code doesn't visibly do something, despite having a `print` in the code. I am trying to read the file `NR.txt`, to `$contents`. The file is in the same folder as the HTML-file, but I have also tried it with the full path, which results in the same output.

Here my code:

```
<html>
<title>
How many pizzas?
</title>
<body>
hello
<?php
$filename = "NR.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
print "$contents";
print "1";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code results in this page:

```
hello
```

I do not know what the problem is here, I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Ye... It works now, srry.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in the code (file does not exist etc) and error reporting turned off (default with many servers). So the script breaks at that point. Suggest to make sure it's a `.php` file and [error reporting is turned on](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/).

Comment: @DanFromGermany Well, it was a `.html` file, so it works now I saved it as a `.php`. Thank you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your document has .php extension, not .html